# IDA(4.9) Is it possible to change definitions of imported functions?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

Is it possible to change argument types/names of arguments of imported functions like StretchBlt in IDA 4.9?
It's painful and error-prone to manually change from

```
...
.text:0040A49E                 push    eax             ; HDC
.text:0040A49F                 push    36h             ; int
.text:0040A4A1                 push    48h             ; int
.text:0040A4A3                 push    5Ah             ; int
.text:0040A4A5                 push    0               ; int
.text:0040A4A7                 push    ecx             ; HDC
.text:0040A4A8                 call    edi ; StretchBlt
```

to

```
...
.text:0040A49E                 push    eax             ; HDC srcHDC
.text:0040A49F                 push    36h             ; int destHeight
.text:0040A4A1                 push    48h             ; int destWidth
.text:0040A4A3                 push    5Ah             ; int destY
.text:0040A4A5                 push    0               ; int destX
.text:0040A4A7                 push    ecx             ; HDC destHDC
.text:0040A4A8                 call    edi ; StretchBlt
```

each time

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing an .IDC script to search for that block of comment, then adjust the previous lines comments.